# In VI editor how to define variable in opened file to open other file by gf

Tags: linux, shell, vi

I have opened one file in vi editor and in this file path of the another file is mentioned as the

```
export abc=$xyz/code/function/pqr.txt

path=$xyz/code/function/java_func.txt
```

Here  `xyz = /user/main_data`

Now I want to open file pqr.txt and java_func.txt by command gf, so I have to set variable xyz.

Then how can I set variable xyz in opened vi file?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww IMO, this is indeed a programming/development question, but OP didn't describe it well. it is something like, how to set environment variable/shell variable in vim.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is actually for vim. I *guess* the vi you meant is vim too. Because you are expecting the `gf` to work.

You can set shell variable(environment variables) in vim. It is :

```
:let $xyz="the/value/you/want"
```

Then you can visual-select the path then `gf` to jump to your target.

Comment: Thanks. But if I declared variable as  path=${xyz}/code/function/java_func.txt